# Unable to start VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently tried to start VSC but nothing came up I waited around 15 min but still nothing happend so I tried to run it with CMD and then I found that I got some invalid token (I don't have Node.js) here this is what happend when I tried to run it this is what the log gave out:

```
Y:\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:1
.58a4.6,4.6,0,0,1-2.11-.46v-1a4.33,4.33,0,0,0,2.09.61q2.4,0,2.4-2.55v-.71h0a2.63,2.63,0,0,1-4.19.38,3.46,3.46,0,0,1-.74-2.33,4,4,0,0,1,.8-2.63,2.66,2.66,0,0,1,2.18-1,2.12,2.12,0,0,1,1.95,1.05h0v-.9h1Zm-1-2.42v-1a1.86,1.86,0,0,0-.52-1.33,1.73,1.73,0,0,0-1.3-.55,1.81,1.81,0,0,0-1.51.7,3.13,3.13,0,0,0-.55,2,2.69,2.69,0,0,0,.52,1.74,1.69,1.69,0,0,0,1.39.65,1.81,1.81,0,0,0,1.43-.62A2.32,2.32,0,0,0,104.93,95.39Z"/><path class="cls-3" d="M113.3,95.34h-4.59a2.43,2.43,0,0,0,.58,1.68,2,2,0,0,0,1.54.59,3.19,3.19,0,0,0,2-.72v1a3.77,3.77,0,0,1-2.27.62,2.75,2.75,0,0,1-2.17-.89,3.63,3.63,0,0,1-.79-2.49,3.55,3.55,0,0,1,.86-2.47,2.76,2.76,0,0,1,2.14-1,2.44,2.44,0,0,1,2,.83,3.44,3.44,0,0,1,.7,2.29Zm-1.07-.88a2.12,2.12,0,0,0-.44-1.4,1.48,1.48,0,0,0-1.19-.5,1.68,1.68,0,0,0-1.25.53,2.4,2.4,0,0,0-.63,1.38Z"/><path class="cls-3" d="M127.86,98.33h-1.06V92.22q0-.72.09-1.77h0a5.69,5.69,0,0,1-.27.88l-3.11,7H123l-3.1-6.94a5.42,5.42,0,0,1-.27-.93h0q0,.54.05,1.78v6.09h-1v-9.1H120l2.7

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:942:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Y:\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js:5:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1014:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at startup (Y:\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\main.js:8:176)
    at onReady (Y:\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\main.js:8:422)
```

But anyway I already tried to run it with some diffrent options like: compatibility settings, running as admin and checked if I got Nods.js if that caused the troubles

Thanks in advance ^=^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like after reinstalling it (and converted it to portable) it works now I don't know if it was because of an plugin or not but what I know it works now I still don't know the awnser but it seems like reinstalling done the trick :/

Comment: If you are on Windows. You may not find VS Code in the list of programs to uninstall. When you try to install VS Code, it will ask you to uninstall the previous version. I skipped that and it still worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi**, Did you install nodejs in your system. VS Code requires nodejs since it is built with `electron`. If you have node but this error still occurs try reinstalling VS Code.

Comment: Hry Hey thanks for you answer but it seems like the error still happens any other idea?

Comment: Hey, i can't think of anything that is immediately obvious. Did you try reinstalling vs code as i said above.If you didn't re install vs code the only thing i can think of is that some files required for vs code to run might be missing.

Comment: Please try running the following command in your terminal ```code --verbose```. And please post the output. Or run this command ```code --user-data-dir``` and try again

Comment: It might also be the fact that you are missing the required dependencies so even after the above steps the error persists try ```sudo apt-get install -f```. It might just work.

Comment: Hey Hey thanks for these many solutions the same errors accure https://pastebin.com/8usMhFk6

Comment: I can't think of anymore solutions, thank you taking the time to look at my solutions.

Comment: You might be able to get a solution if you ask on the official forum for vs code.

Comment: offical forum? Is there one existing as I tried to use that support page it said I have to pay something to do so

Comment: Sorry my bad it's their ```FAQ``` at [code.visualstudio.com](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ)

Comment: Well thanks for the help anyway I'm just gonna leave this thread open till I found an answer or if I get an answer here :/ but still thanks for the help and time you gave me ^^

Comment: Yep that sounds like a very good idea. I'm sure you'd find an answer,meanwhile you wait try ```sublime``` it's awsome.

Comment: looks good thank you for that recommendation time to switch it to that software is it good for portable use? is it able to import VSC plugins?

Comment: It is very portable and fast maybe even faster than VSC because it's built in c++ unlike VSC which is built on electron. It also supports alot of plugins eventhough those are not vscode plugins. Ps you might need to install an extension to use the terminal inside of the editor.Unlike VSC  which has a built in terminal.

Comment: haha ok but I really don't use the terminal that much because I mostly only code in HTML/CSS or Hacknet XML

Comment: I'm sure you'll love ```sublime```. Enjoy